# How to change Choose button title in UIImagePickerViewController?

Tags: iphone, button, uiimagepickercontroller

When we use UIImagePickerViewController class, if we allow editing YES then we found the same view i attached here, As per my work requirement i have to change the "Choose" button title to "Accept", How could we do this? 
I didn't use overlay view for this.

[image]

Every helpful reply would be highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [UIImagePickerController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) says `The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified`. In short, you need to use `cameraOverlayView` if you want customization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use an [overlay view](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraOverlayView) to create a custom toolbar with the buttons you want on it. If you modify the buttons on the existing `UIImagePickerController` Apple will probably reject your app, as that is explicitly prohibited (as documented in the link).